# MySQL Cluster - The table is full

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I created MySQL Cluster with 1 management, 2 data and 2 SQL nodes. When I run my app (spring boot) the app crashes while creating tables with the error:

```
The table 'user' is full [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY...
```

I have checked the following:

`innodb_data_file_path`, `tmp_table_size`, `innodb_file_per_table` and `max_heap_table_size` and the values are the same as in my local environment. What else can I check to solve this error?

Edit 1:

Previous foreign keys have been successfully created up until said table.

Answer (score 0):

This is foreign key check problem.
Add **NOCHECK** to your foreign key construction.

```
ALTER TABLE user
    WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_user FOREIGN KEY (....) REFERENCES t1(....) 
GO
```

and then enable it:

```
ALTER TABLE user
      WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
 GO
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Also since I am using liquibase this isn't a viable solution